# How can AWS Glue access IP whitelisted resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

If I have a service that needs to have IP whitelisting, how can I connect AWS Glue to it? I read that I seem to be able to put AWS Glue in a private VPC and configure a NAT gateway. I can then allow my NAT IP to connect to the service. However, I cannot find anyway to configure my Glue Job to run inside a subnet/VPC. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The job will run automatically in a VPC if you attach a Database connection to a resource which is inside the VPC. For example, I have a job that reads data from S3 and writes into an Aurora database in a private VPC using a Glue connection (configured as JDBC).

That job automatically has access to all the resources inside the VPC, as [explained here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/start-connecting.html). If the VPC has enabled NAT for external access, then your job can also take advantage of that.

Note if you use a connection that requires VPC and you use S3, you will need to enable an endpoint for S3 in that VPC as well.

Comment: Hmm, what if I dont need a DB connection. I just want to connect to a private API for example. Or rather in this case, the API is actually outside VPC but I need an IP address to do IP whitelisting. So I am planning to put it inside VPC and use the NAT IP to do whitelisting

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Glue will use VPC only when it needs to connect to a resource in the VPC. As you mentioned, it doesn't has explicit VPC configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for your question is answered here --  https://stackoverflow.com/a/64414639 Note that Glue is a 'managed' service so it does not release any list IP addresses such that can be whitelisted. As a workaround you can use a EC2 instance to run your custom python OR pyspark script and whitelist the IP address of that particular EC2 instance